# Return object with max value in linked list using recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, nodes

I have a custom linked list with `Student` object stored as `Node` object in it. I have a method, `public Student worstStudentRec(Node list)` which takes the head `Node` (list) and recursively finds the node containing the `Student` with the highest *GPA*. My code below works for this purpose, but I'm confused on whether or not I can change the method code so that it works without declaring variables outside of that class. For example, I declared `private Node baseCase` to serve as the node containing the `Student` with the *lowest GPA*, and `worstStudent` to serve as my eventual return variable. I'm completely stuck and can't figure out whether this can be done without declaring these variables outside of the method or not.
My code for the method is below. Thanks!

```
  private Node baseCase = new Node (new Student ("", Double.MAX_VALUE, 0));
  private Student worstStudent;
  public Student worstStudentRec(Node list)
  {
    if (list == null)
      return worstStudent;
    else if (list.next == null)
        return worstStudent;
    else
      worstStudent = (baseCase.data.compareTo(list.data) <= 0) ? baseCase.data : list.data; 
      baseCase = (baseCase.data.compareTo(list.data) <= 0) ? baseCase : list;
      return worstStudentRec(list.next);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

```
  public Student worstStudentRec(Node list)
  {
    if (list == null)
      return null;  // add null-handling
    else if (list.next == null)
        return list.data;

    Node theWorstFromOthers = worstStudentRec(list.next);
    return (list.data.compareTo(theWorstFromOthers.data) <= 0) ? list.data : theWorstFromOthers.data;
  }
```

When you use recursion - keep in mind that you can do not only chain execution but also a computation. In other words - you can(and in many cases) should use result of recursion in your computations.

Comment: There is an issue with the Node theWorstFromOthers... line. worstStudentRec returns a Student object which cannot be assigned to the Node object ehWorstFromOthers. I changed theWorstFromOthers to Student type and removed .data from it in the return statement. This works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

yes you can avoid declaring those outside..

for worst student you can pass another variable `worsTudentNode`. So in the method check whether the current student is worse than the previous `worstStudent`. If yes then pass the current student to the next recursion call else use the previous one.

Here is a pseudo code

```
public Student worstStudentRec(Node list, Node worstStudent)
  {
    if (list == null || list.next == null)
      return worstStudent;
    else{
      worstStudent = compare with current and add the worse
      return worstStudentRec(list.next, worstStudent);
   }
  }
```